# Не понятная проблема с кнопкой(button)

Tags: python, django, forms, django-model

Проблема в том что при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, никакого действия.
метод пост не определён то есть оно должно возбуждать ошибку по этому поводу, но ничего не происходит.
Я хочу сделать создание тега с помощью форм django

Сам класс тега, который будет создаваться через форму:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Форма:

```
from django import forms
from blog.models import Tag, Post
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class TagForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    def clean_slug(self):
        new_slug = str.lower(self.cleaned_data['slug'])

        if new_slug == 'create':
            raise ValidationError('Slug may not be created')
        else:
            return new_slug

    def save(self):
        new_tag = Tag.objects.create(title=self.cleaned_data['title'], slug=self.cleaned_data['slug'])
        return new_tag
```

Урлы:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),
    path('post/create/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post_create_url'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),
    path('tags/', tag_list, name='tag_list_url'),
    path('tag/create', TagCreate.as_view(), name='tag_create_url'),
    path('tag/<str:slug>', TagDetail.as_view(), name='tag_detail_url'),
]
```

вьюха:

```
class TagCreate(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = TagForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/tag_create.html', context={'form': form})
```

шаблон:

```
{% extends 'blog/base_blog.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Tag Create - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="{% url 'tag_create_url' %}" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}

       {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ field.errors }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                {{ field.label }}
                {{ field }}
            </div>

       {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Tag</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

В чём можешь быть проблема, уже множество раз переписывал.

Comment: А где собственно обработчик формы? Я вижу в вашем view только обработку get-запроса.

Comment: @zakiroof Он у меня указан, проблема в том что даже при нажатии без определённого post запроса ничего не происходит, даже ошибка не возникает, и страница не обновляется, просто ничего